# Using the graph API, is it possible to return both sizes for the user picture?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100)&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token=
```

I want to also include the large size of the picture: `picture.type(large)`

Is there a way to include it in the same call? Meaning retrieving both versions.

Currently, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Syntax error \"Field picture specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1\" at character 76: name,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large),picture.width(100).height(100),email", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

with : `https://graph.facebook.com/mefields=picture.width(100).height(100),picture.type(large)&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token=`

Comment: You can use batch request. According to the `error`, this was possible in `v2.0` and `v1.0` of API

Comment: Oh good! I wasn't aware of that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests?locale=fr_FR

Answer (score 1):

yes! it's possible. you can use [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#batching)  . In this case you should use separate completion handlers for each request.

Other solution is to use field aliasing like this guy recommends : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35341593/5612119