# iOS Facebook Graph Request multiple picture sizes

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's graph API and am trying to get two different picture sizes of a user's current profile picture. One picture I would like to be size 250x250, and the other picture I would like be size 1080x1080. Here is my current code:

```
    let params = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(1080).height(1080)"]
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

This returns the URL to a picture of size 1080x1080 and works. Now if I change the params to add a request for a picture of size 250x250:

```
let params = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(250).height(250), picture.width(1080).height(1080)"]
```

I get this error basically saying I can't use the field `picture` more than once:

```
Syntax error "Field picture specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1" at character 94: first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(250).height(250), picture.width(1080).height(1080)
```

Does this mean the only way to accomplish what I want is to make a [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests)? And if that's the case, is there a function that gets called once both batch requests have completed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's another (better) way of doing this with just a single, non-batch request by using [field aliasing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields), which I came across recently when I had the same issue.

In the OP's case the fields parameter would be set to:

```
first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(250).height(250).as(picture_small), picture.width(1080).height(1080).as(picture_large)
```

The response will then include two fields named picture_small and picture_large containing the respective picture data. E.g:

```
{
  "first_name": "Mark",
  "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
  "picture_small": {
    "data": {
      "height": 320,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xtl1/v/t1.0-1/p320x320/12208495_10102454385528521_4749095086285673716_n.jpg?oh=e14ffdec03ceb6f30da80d1c4c5c4c02&oe=57254837",
      "width": 320
    }
  },
  "picture_large": {
    "data": {
      "height": 547,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xtl1/v/t1.0-1/12208495_10102454385528521_4749095086285673716_n.jpg?oh=b008ae35daeea9b0d9babbee9d701a34&oe=572336EC",
      "width": 547
    }
  },
  "id": "4"
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I was searching for such a feature for quite some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to get the large size images. Check the following query. 
`NSString * graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?fields=photos.fields(id,link,source)", albumID];`

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

the *boring* one is to make two requests. while the better solution is to make a batch request:

This is the cURL batch request to my profile, and it works:

> curl -XPOST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4" -d "access_token=put_your_access_token_here" -i -d 'batch=[{"method" : "GET", "relative_url":"me?fields=first_name,last_name,picture.width(250).height(250)"},{"method" : "GET", "relative_url" : "me?fields=first_name,last_name,picture.width(1080).height(1080)"}]' -i

You just need to put your access token.

Comment: You could leave out the part that asks for the other fields a second time, and make that second request URL just `me?picture.width(1080).height(1080)` only.

Comment: @CBroe but then the problem is when I just want to retrieve 50 small thumbnail photos when displaying all the users, I will be loading 50 1080x1080 images which is unnecessary and a waste of data. The 1080x1080 image is to be displayed only if a user's thumbnail photo is clicked on, and then it will load it

Comment: You won’t be _loading_ them, you would just be retrieving their URLs from the API – store them somewhere (or keep them in the data structure they are already returned in from the API), and then load them when needed only (when their thumbnail was clicked on.)